# f.collection_select with name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, collections

I hope someone can help me.
I have a table with the name "location_location_relationships". If you create a new entry you can select two locations (predecessor and successor) which are from a "locaions" table. In addition you can select a tour. These are coming from table "tours". The locations selection is working. But the tours makes some problems. First I had nothing in the models everything worked but the selection wrote not the names but the ids in the "location_location_relationships" table. But I want the names in there. So I completed the models of "tours" and "location_location_relationships". In the selection there are the names of the tours now but if I press the Button "create" I get an error massage: 
Tour(#96769428) expected, got String(#1848192)

and it shows me the error in the location_location_relationship_controller.rb in: 
  'def create

```
@location_location_relationship = LocationLocationRelationship.new(location_location_relationship_params)'
```

Has anyone an idea what I did wrong?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

This is my location_location_relationships_form.html.erb where the collection_select is in:

```
<%= form_for(@location_location_relationship) do |f| %>
<% if @location_location_relationship.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(@location_location_relationship.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this location_location_relationship from being saved:</h2>

  <ul>
  <% @location_location_relationship.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label 'Von Ort' %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :predecessor_id, Location.all, :id, :name %>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label 'Zu Ort' %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :successor_id, Location.all, :id, :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label 'Tour' %><br>
<%= f.collection_select :tour, Tour.all, :id, :name_of_tour, prompt: true %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label 'Distanz' %><br>
<%= f.text_field :distance, type: "number", min:0 %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

My model of the location_location_relationships:

```
class LocationLocationRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :successor, class_name: "Location"
belongs_to :predecessor, class_name: "Location"
validates :successor_id, presence: true
validates :predecessor_id, presence: true

belongs_to :tour

validates :tour, presence: true
validates :distance, :numericality => true
#  validates :sequence, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}
#  validates :binary_variable, :numericality => {:only_integer => true}
end
```

And my tours model:

```
class Tour < ActiveRecord::Base
#validates :tour, presence: true
has_many :location_location_relationships
def name_of_tour
    name
end
end
```

And the location_location_relationships controller:

```
class LocationLocationRelationshipsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_location_location_relationship, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


# GET /location_location_relationships
# GET /location_location_relationships.json
def index
@location_location_relationships = LocationLocationRelationship.all
end

# GET /location_location_relationships/1
# GET /location_location_relationships/1.json
def show
end

# GET /location_location_relationships/new
def new
@location_location_relationship = LocationLocationRelationship.new
end

# GET /location_location_relationships/1/edit
def edit
end

# POST /location_location_relationships
# POST /location_location_relationships.json
def create
@location_location_relationship = LocationLocationRelationship.new(location_location_relationship_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @location_location_relationship.save
    format.html { redirect_to @location_location_relationship, notice: 'Die Distanz wurde angelegt.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @location_location_relationship }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @location_location_relationship.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# PATCH/PUT /location_location_relationships/1
# PATCH/PUT /location_location_relationships/1.json
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @location_location_relationship.update(location_location_relationship_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @location_location_relationship, notice: 'Die Distanz wurde aktualisiert.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @location_location_relationship }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @location_location_relationship.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# DELETE /location_location_relationships/1
# DELETE /location_location_relationships/1.json
def destroy
@location_location_relationship.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to location_location_relationships_url, notice: 'Die Distanz wurde gelöscht.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
end
private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_location_location_relationship
  @location_location_relationship = LocationLocationRelationship.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def location_location_relationship_params
    params.require(:location_location_relationship).permit(:predecessor_id, :successor_id, :tour, :distance, :sequence, :binary_variable)
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> Tour(#96769428) expected, got String(#1848192)

You should change `tour` to `tour_id`

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label 'Tour' %><br>
<%= f.collection_select :tour_id, Tour.all, :id, :name_of_tour, prompt: true %>
</div>
```

And also in `location_location_relationship_params`

```
def location_location_relationship_params
  params.require(:location_location_relationship).permit(:predecessor_id, :successor_id, :tour_id, :distance, :sequence, :binary_variable)
end
```